# SharePoint sites search using Microsoft Graph api returns deleted sites

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365

When I do a search for SharePoint online sites using Microsoft graph endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*`, it returns very old deleted sites along with  active sites in SharePoint admin centre. These deleted sites are not in 'Deleted sites' of SharePoint admin centre. When I've accessed these sites in SharePoint online using the site URL provided by the graph search api, it gives '404 NOT FOUND'. When I've accessed the site using graph api `GET /sites/{site-id}`, it gives 'itemNotFound' error. Is there anyway to exclude these sites from the search response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently have a way to do this in the Graph APIs. I would suggest going to User Voice [**here**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) and putting the request there so it makes its way onto our backlog.

Thanks!